# Make OSX listen to a specific sequence of keys, and execute [anything]

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Here's the use case.

I use aText, a text expander. It has a hotkey to show a list of saved text expansions. I want to remove the need for manually pressing this hotkey. Therefore I need my OS to look at my keyboard and trigger this hotkey automatically when a specific sequence is found.

Ex.

1. My hotkey to show the text expander list of expansions is `CMD` + `SHIFT` + `S`
2. All of my expansion shortcuts starts with `;;`
3. When I write or press `;;`, I want my OS to send `CMD`+`SHIFT`+`S` to the system, and thus triggering the expander list.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: do you need that window open to be able to use the triggers, or is it just as a reminder of which key-sequence to use?

Comment: It's pretty much a reminder only.

Comment: ah, OK - then my idea wouldn't work. I was going to suggest moving them over to system prefs > keyboard > text instead.

Comment: I see, I need the extended capabilities a dedicated text expander though. I got one solution working, I posted it as an answer to the question if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after some tinkering I have a bit of a hack to make it work for me and it works a little bit like this.

1) I dowloaded an open source keylogger, and modified it to not log anything, just listen.

```
...  
char * currentKey = convertKeyCode(keyCode);  
char * target = ";";  
if( currentKey == previousKey && currentKey == target ){
...
```

2) When it sees that I pressed the two keys I choose it will invoke an apple script like this

```
...
system("echo \"tell application \\\"System Events\\\" to keystroke \\\"S\\\" using {command down, shift down}\" | osascript");
...
```

Which is the key I have in aText.

This works pretty well but I will wait for neater solutions before I set the question as answered.